# Magento, create Superuser who has to accept orders

Tags: magento-1.9

Im using Magento 1.9.0.1.

Is it possible to create a Superuser, who gets an E-mail, everytime one of his Subusers makes an Order.
The order should not be placed until the Superuser accepts the Order.